# .Net core api 2.2 request to Coldfusion Api character issue inserting to MSSQL db

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-2.0, coldfusion-10

I make the request to coldfusion api from .net core api as shown below

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

var jsonSeri_ = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_frmCustomerTicket);

Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(jsonSeri_);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{

    streamWriter.Write(msg);

}
```

in coldfusion api I get the request json as below

```
<cfif cgi.content_type EQ "application/json">
      <cfset _deserializeJSON = deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content))>
    <cfelse>
{"userFname":"","userEmail":"","companyId":1,"priority_id":3,"userLTopic":"donanım arızası","pdesc":"cookie güzel bir şekilde çalışıyorrrrr"}
```

then, I send the json data to another page to insert the data to MSSQL database.

this is how I pass the data:

```
 <cfset var formStruct = _deserializeJSON />
 <cfinclude template="queryexecute.cfm">
```

In another page, I use the code as below.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">

<cfparam name="formStruct" default="">

INSERT INTO
  G_SERVICE
   (
                            
     SERVICE_ACTIVE,
     ISREAD,
     SERVICECAT_ID,
     SERVICE_STATUS_ID,
     PRIORITY_ID,
     COMMETHOD_ID,
     SERVICE_HEAD,
     SERVICE_DETAI
 )
 VALUES
  ( 
    1
    , 0
    , 1
    , 92
    , #formStruct.priority_id#
    , 0
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR" value="#(formStruct.userLTopic)#">
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR" value="<p>  #(formStruct.pdesc)#  </p>">
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#now()#">
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" value="#now()#">
)
```

The weird thing is that, when it is being inserted, the formstruct parameters changes as below:

I can not get why it changes while being inserted as Ä±,Ã¼ .

```
{"userFname":"","userEmail":"","companyId":1,"priority_id":3,"userLTopic":"donanÄ±m arÄ±zasÄ±","pdesc":"cookie gÃ¼zel bir ÅŸekilde Ã§alÄ±ÅŸÄ±yorrrrr"}
```

Comment: On the .Net side you change the character set from UTF-8 to ISO-****.  On the CF side, you don't supply the `encoding` param to the `toString(...)` call.  Shouldn't the JSON string be converted from ISO at that point?  I notice you're using UTF-8 when you insert the data, but there's no conversion from ISO.

Comment: What is the column type - and collation - on the database side? Your cfqueryparams use `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` which maps to `nvarchar` in SQL Server. Those will be using UCS-2 encoding, unless your SQL Server database is using an _SC collation (Supplementary Characters) which then use UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Before inserting data into the database, whether the characters are correct, try to set a break point to check it. And you could also use SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to check the database table data. If you store character data that reflects multiple languages in SQL Server (SQL Server 2005 (9.x) and later), use Unicode data types (nchar, nvarchar, and ntext) instead of non-Unicode data types (char, varchar, and text).

Comment: I did what you guys recommended but none of them seems work except I sent the request via .net razor pages ajax and it did work, the context character set did not change. However when I intend to send the data via .net core web api 2.0, the context data breaks while being inserted to database. That is really strange. And I have to send the data via .net core web api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing I have just added is `charset=utf-8` to contentType. Let me share the whole code .net core web api 2.0

> request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");
            
  request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  request.Method = "POST";

   using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
   {
       string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_frmCustomerTicket);
       streamWriter.Write(json2);
    }

   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   var result = "";
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
     {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
```